# How to pass data from C to assembly

Tags: c, assembly

I made a program which is in two parts. 
First part is written in C and its taking data from the user. The second one is written in assembly and its making operations. 
I have problem with passing data from dynamic allocated array to assembly module. Program is not working correctly. What I did wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

extern "C" near void licz_sr( int* );
extern "C" near void licz_znaki( char* );

int *tablica_liczb_dynamiczna;
char tablica_znakow[28]; //[0] = ilosc, [1] = kod szukany, [27] = ilosc wystapien
int wielkosc_tablicy = 0;
int kod;

int menu(), losuj_liczby(), losuj_znaki(), licz_srednia(), sprawdz_ilosc_znakow();
void wczytaj_liczby(), wczytaj_znaki();

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    //tablica_liczb[0] = 5;
    tablica_znakow[0] = 25;
    menu();

    return 0;
}

int menu(){

    printf("\n\n\nCo mam zrobic?\nW = Wyliczyc srednia z losowej tablicy\nP = Policzyc ilosc znakow w losowej tablicy\nX = Wyjsc z programu\n");

    kod = getchar();
    getchar();

    if (kod == 87 || kod == 119) {
        //losuj_liczby();
        wczytaj_liczby();
        //licz_srednia();
    }
    else if (kod == 80 || kod == 112){
        //losuj_znaki();
        wczytaj_znaki();
        sprawdz_ilosc_znakow();
    }
    else if (kod == 88 || kod == 120){
        return 0;
    }
    menu();
}

void wczytaj_liczby()
{
    printf("Ile znakow wprowadzic? ");
    scanf("%d",&wielkosc_tablicy);
    printf("wielkosc tab: "); printf("%d",wielkosc_tablicy);

    tablica_liczb_dynamiczna = (int*)malloc(wielkosc_tablicy * sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0; i < wielkosc_tablicy; i++){  
        tablica_liczb_dynamiczna[i] = NULL;
    }

    printf("\n\nWczytaj liczby:");

    for(int j = 0; j < wielkosc_tablicy; j++)

    {
        scanf("%d", &tablica_liczb_dynamiczna[j]);

        printf("\n");
        printf("%d", j);printf("element tab "); printf("%d",tablica_liczb_dynamiczna[j]);
        printf("\n");
        tablica_liczb_dynamiczna[j] = tablica_liczb_dynamiczna[j]-48;
    }
    licz_srednia();
}

void wczytaj_znaki()

{

    for (int i =2; i < tablica_znakow[0]+2; i++)

    {

        tablica_znakow[i] = NULL;

    }

    printf("\n\nWczytaj znaki:");

    char polecenie[25];

    fgets( polecenie, 25, stdin );

    for (int j =2; j < tablica_znakow[0]+2; j++)

    {

        tablica_znakow[j] = polecenie[j-2];

    }

}



int licz_srednia()

{
    licz_sr(tablica_liczb_dynamiczna);



    //printf("\n\nSrednia jest rowna: "); printf("%c", tablica_liczb[6]+48); printf(", a reszta jest rowna: "); printf("%c", tablica_liczb[7]+48);

    printf("\n\nSrednia jest rowna: "); printf("%c", tablica_liczb_dynamiczna[6]+48); printf(", a reszta jest rowna: "); printf("%c", tablica_liczb_dynamiczna[7]+48);

    //cout << "Srednia jest rowna: " << tablica_liczb_dynamiczna[6]+48 << ", a reszta: " << tablica_liczb_dynamiczna[7]+48 << endl;

    return 0;

}


int sprawdz_ilosc_znakow()

{

    printf("\n\nWystapienia jakiego znaku mam liczyc? ");

    tablica_znakow[1] = getchar();

    getchar();

    //printf("\n\n");

    licz_znaki(tablica_znakow);



    printf("\nZnak \""); printf("%c", tablica_znakow[1]); printf("\" wystapil "); printf("%c", tablica_znakow[27]+48); 

    if (tablica_znakow[27] != 1)        printf(" razy.");

    else                                            printf(" raz.");

}
```

and the assembly part.

```
.model small, C


Dane            SEGMENT

Tablica         DB          (?)
Ilosc           DB          (?)

Dane            ENDS


PUBLIC licz_znaki

.code


licz_znaki    PROC near


            push    bp
            mov     bp, sp
            mov     di, [bp+4]
            ; [bp+4] = adres
            ; [di] = liczba
            ; [bp+12] = tab[1]
            ; [bp+16] = tab[2]
            ; [bp+20] = tab[3]
            ; [bp+24] = tab[4]
            xor     cx, cx
            mov     cl, [di]
            inc     di
            ;inc        di
            xor     ax, ax
            xor     bx, bx
            xor     dx, dx
            mov     ah, [di]            ;w ah jest znak, którego szukamy
            inc     di
            ;inc        di
Petla_z:
            mov     al, [di]            ;w ah jest aktualny znak z tablicy
            cmp     al, ah
            jz          Dodaj_do_wyniku
            Powrot_do_petli:
            inc     di
            ;inc        di
            loop        Petla_z

Dodaj_do_wyniku:
            jcxz        Koncowka
            inc     bx              ;bh przechowuje ilosc wystapien
            jmp     short   Powrot_do_petli

Koncowka:
            mov     [di], bx

            pop     bp
            ret

licz_znaki ENDP

PUBLIC licz_sr

.code


licz_sr    PROC near


            push    bp
            mov     bp, sp
            mov     di, [bp+4]
            mov     bx, [di]
            ; [bp+4] = adres
            ; [di] = liczba
            ; [bp+12] = tab[1]
            ; [bp+16] = tab[2]
            ; [bp+20] = tab[3]
            ; [bp+24] = tab[4]
            xor     cx, cx
            mov     cl, [di]
            inc     di
            inc     di
            xor     ax, ax
            xor     dx, dx
Petla_l:
            add     ax, [di]
            inc     di
            inc     di
            loop        Petla_l

            div     bx

            mov     [di], ax
            inc     di
            inc     di
            mov     [di], dx        ;wj

            pop     bp
            ret

licz_sr ENDP


end
```

Translated C module:
Explanation: Program with normal array(not dynamic) was downloading data to `[8]` elements array. User could input `5` numbers. Assembly module  return average to `[6]` element of table and rest of division to `[7]` element of table. Then C module output [7] and [6] elements of table using `printf` function.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>

    extern "C" near void count_averageExtern( int* );
    extern "C" near void count_characters( char* );

    int *dynamic_arrau;
    //char tablica_znakow[28]; //[0] = ilosc, [1] = kod szukany, [27] = ilosc wystapien
    int size_of_array = 0;
    int code;

    int menu(), count_average(), sprawdz_ilosc_znakow();
    void download_numbers(), wczytaj_znaki();

    int main() {
        srand(time(NULL));

        //tablica_liczb[0] = 5;
        tableOfCharacters[0] = 25;
        menu();

        return 0;
    }

    int menu(){

        printf("\n\n\nWhat to do?\nW = average\nP = not important\nX = exit\n");

        code = getchar();
        getchar();

        if (code == 87 || code == 119) {
            //losuj_liczby();
            download_numbers();
            count_average();
        }
        /*else if (kod == 80 || kod == 112){
            //losuj_znaki();
            wczytaj_znaki();
            sprawdz_ilosc_znakow();
        }*/
        else if (kod == 88 || kod == 120){
            return 0;
        }
        menu();
    }

    void download_numbers()
    {
        printf("How many numbers input? ");
        scanf("%d",&size_of_array);

        dynamic_arrau = (int*)malloc(size_of_array * sizeof(int));

        for(int i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++){ 
            dynamic_arrau[i] = NULL;
        }

        printf("\n\Input numbers:");

        for(int j = 0; j < size_of_array; j++)

        {
            scanf("%d", &dynamic_arrau[j]);

            printf("\n");
            tablica_liczb_dynamiczna[j] = tablica_liczb_dynamiczna[j]-48;
        }
        licz_srednia();
    }

    /*void wczytaj_znaki() {

        for (int i =2; i < tablica_znakow[0]+2; i++)

        {

            tablica_znakow[i] = NULL;

        }

        printf("\n\nWczytaj znaki:");

        char polecenie[25];

        fgets( polecenie, 25, stdin );

        for (int j =2; j < tablica_znakow[0]+2; j++)

        {

            tablica_znakow[j] = polecenie[j-2];

        }

    }
    */


    int count_average()

    {
        count_averageExtern(dynamic_arrau);
        //printf("\n\nSrednia jest rowna: "); printf("%c", tablica_liczb[6]+48); printf(", a reszta jest rowna: "); printf("%c", tablica_liczb[7]+48);
        printf("\n\nAverage: "); printf("%c", dynamic_arrau[6]+48); printf(", and rest of division: "); printf("%c", dynamic_arrau[7]+48);
        return 0;
    }


   /* int sprawdz_ilosc_znakow()

    {

        printf("\n\nWystapienia jakiego znaku mam liczyc? ");

        tablica_znakow[1] = getchar();

        getchar();

        //printf("\n\n");

        licz_znaki(tablica_znakow);



        printf("\nZnak \""); printf("%c", tablica_znakow[1]); printf("\" wystapil "); printf("%c", tablica_znakow[27]+48); 

        if (tablica_znakow[27] != 1)        printf(" razy.");

        else                                            printf(" raz.");

    }*/
```

Translated assembly module:

```
    .model small, C


    Data        SEGMENT

    Tablica         DB          (?)
    Ilosc           DB          (?)

    Data        ENDS


   /* PUBLIC licz_znaki

    .code


    licz_znaki    PROC near


                push    bp
                mov     bp, sp
                mov     di, [bp+4]
                ; [bp+4] = adres
                ; [di] = liczba
                ; [bp+12] = tab[1]
                ; [bp+16] = tab[2]
                ; [bp+20] = tab[3]
                ; [bp+24] = tab[4]
                xor     cx, cx
                mov     cl, [di]
                inc     di
                ;inc        di
                xor     ax, ax
                xor     bx, bx
                xor     dx, dx
                mov     ah, [di]            ;w ah jest znak, którego szukamy
                inc     di
                ;inc        di
    Petla_z:
                mov     al, [di]            ;w ah jest aktualny znak z tablicy
                cmp     al, ah
                jz          Dodaj_do_wyniku
                Powrot_do_petli:
                inc     di
                ;inc        di
                loop        Petla_z

    Dodaj_do_wyniku:
                jcxz        Koncowka
                inc     bx              ;bh przechowuje ilosc wystapien
                jmp     short   Powrot_do_petli

    Koncowka:
                mov     [di], bx

                pop     bp
                ret

    licz_znaki ENDP
    */
    PUBLIC count_averageExtern

    .code


    count_averageExtern    PROC near


                push    bp
                mov     bp, sp
                mov     di, [bp+4]
                mov     bx, [di]
                ; [bp+4] = addres
                ; [di] = number
                ; [bp+12] = tab[1]
                ; [bp+16] = tab[2]
                ; [bp+20] = tab[3]
                ; [bp+24] = tab[4]
                xor     cx, cx
                mov     cl, [di]
                inc     di
                inc     di
                xor     ax, ax
                xor     dx, dx
    Loop_l:
                add     ax, [di]
                inc     di
                inc     di
                loop        Loop_1

                div     bx

                mov     [di], ax
                inc     di
                inc     di
                mov     [di], dx        ;wj

                pop     bp
                ret

    count_averageExtern ENDP


    end
```

In the `//` is not important part of program. But i think it is still needed to understand idea.

I am using Broland C(BC) in Dos shell. It works fine. This program should take a data from a user(The user determines the number of numbers). Downloaded data is saved in the dynamic array. Then in assembly module program counts average of data in array and its returning the value. Its easy with normal arrays but a bit tricky with dynamic... I dont have any idea how to start.

Comment: “It doesn't work” is not an error description. Please tell us what what you expect the program to do and what happens instead.

Comment: Deciphering our code is not made easier by the fact that it uses identifiers and comments in a language I have no clue about.  In general, you'll increase your chances to get a useful answer if you post your code in English.

Comment: The description of [tag:assembly] requires you to also tag instruction set/architecture.

Comment: Tip: I think you could increase the probability of a reopening by converting the Polish variable names to English ones.

Answer (score -1):

There is no general answer, since it is implementation specific. Read the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) standard (draft [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)), you'll probably won't see any mention of x86.

You should read the documentation of the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and of the [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) relevant for your *particular* system, processor, and and C compiler. Some compilers may follow *different* calling conventions (e.g. with per-function annotations or compiler configuration or `#pragma`-s). For x86, read first the wikipage on (various) [x86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) (e.g. `cdecl`, `fastcall` in 16 bits mode, etc ...)

If compiling your `mycsource.c` *C* code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), you could compile with `gcc -fverbose-asm -Wall -O1 -S mycsource.c` and study the generated assembler file `mycsource.s` to understand the calls to assembler functions. You could also use [Inline Assembly Language in C Code](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html).

If you don't use GCC, try to ask your C compiler to emit and keep the assembler code and study it (and understand, guess, or check the calling convention relevant to your issue). If that is not possible, use some disassembler (or the dissassembling facility of your debugger).

Comment: I've downvoted your answer because it is a non-answer. It doesn't contain a single useful thing for OP. Perhaps you meant to write a comment instead?

Comment: No, I mean an answer. Answering "there cannot be a general answer" is really a legitimate answer (and most questions involving [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) - which this question is not - can only get such an answer). Besides, I gave a useful hint in my second paragraph.

Comment: AFAIK gcc doesn't do 16-bit x86, so gcc is not going to help with figuring out the ABI.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch OPs concrete problem most likely has an answer—we just need to figure out what compiler he uses.

Comment: @fuz : He's using Borland C/C++ under DOS according to the latest deleted answer and question update.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I saw this, which is why I voted for reopening.

Comment: Ha can I do that? I mean reopen question. Create the new one and let somebody else to delete it?